# Disable and enable all event listeners for a given event name

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am using a JS library which binds some DOM events with event listeners of its own.

What I want to do is, given an specific event (e.g. `touchstart`), prevent the event listeners in the library from being called. I'd like something like:

```
// Maybe get some dictionary with the list of disabled events listeners
// for each element in the DOM, indexed by the elements themselves
disabledListeners = document.disableEventListenersFor('touchstart')
```

After that, I would like to be able to re-enable the disabled bindings:

```
document.enableEventListenersFor('touchstart', disabledListeners);
```

Specifically, I want to be able to switch back and forth between two modes in the application: one that reacts to all touch events and one that doesn't.

**Edit**: Years have passed, but I think this question might still be interesting. I don't remember exactly what solution I came to, but as I remember, I tried editing the (obfuscated) source of the library itself, every time it bound a listener.

Comment: [Removing EventHandlers](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/removeeventlistenerdetachevent.htm)

Comment: @Event_Horizon Thanks,I think that's not the hardest part, though. The hard part is to save them somwhere before removing them, since I want to be able to re-enable them in some moment after I remove them. (Btw, I also tried using jQuery, and the following seems to work good for removing touch events: `$('*').on('touchmove',false);` )